# SwiftUI: How to set a time picker's range to contain midnight?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, datepicker, timepicker

I am working with SwiftUI 2 and using a `DatePicker` with `displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute`.

I want to allow the user to choose any time between 10 pm and 2 am. Hence, the time range that I want to use contains midnight.

Unfortunately, when I supply the `DatePicker` with this time range, it only allows me to choose times between 10:00 pm and 11:59 pm:

```
@State private var date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 22, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 22, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())!

...

DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: startDate...Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 4, to: startDate)!, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
```

In other words, only times until midnight can be chosen, although the supplied time range also contains 0 am until 2 am (of the next day).

How can this be solved?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I think we should report such a weird behaviour to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `displayedComponents`, everything seems to work as intended.

If your goal is to select any time between 10 pm and 2 am, this means `10PM today` up to `2AM tomorrow`, then displaying just `hourAndMinute` might be confusing

```
DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: startDate...Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 4, to: startDate)!)
```

Removing `displayedComponents`

Comment: Hi Cédric, I'm well aware of this possibility. However, I want to enable the user of my app to choose any point in time during the next 4 hours. So, if it is 10 pm, the user should just easily be able to choose any time between 10 pm and 2 am without worrying about the day. I don't think, this would get to confusing.